# C# (Bot) couldnt connect to online services

Tags: c#, .net, bots

Hello im created my first bot and it works well in local emulator,but when i try to test it in 
https://dev.botframework.com

[image]

There was an error sending this message to your bot

Comment: What is you question exactly?

Comment: I want to run my code in this site,if everything will be ok,then add to Skype

Comment: Have you registered your bot?

Comment: Im registered on azure and then it worked